# To implement horizontal progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am Trying to implement the horizontal progressbar.But I am not understanding how to implement it in my class.Now I have implemented the dialog box which is in the format of sphener,But I want it in horizontal format showing progress of activity I am downloading some contents at that time it should show the progress.

My code is

```
          public class Loginwebview extends Activity {
                WebView webview;
                String url1;
                Bundle bundle=null;
                private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.weblogin);
                    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
                    bundle = new Bundle();
                    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
                    {
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            view.loadUrl(url);
                            url1=url.toString();                
                            bundle.putString("parameter", url1);
                            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Loginwebview.this, "", "Loading...");
                            new Thread() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try{        
                                        if(url1.contains("&mydownloads=true"))  
                                        {
                                            if(url1.contains(".zip"))
                                            {   
                                                sleep(150000);
                                                Intent i1 = new Intent(Loginwebview.this, DownloadZipActivity.class);
                                                i1.putExtras(bundle);
                                                startActivityForResult(i1,0);
                                            }
                                            else 
                                            {
                                                sleep(40000);
                                                Intent i2 = new Intent(Loginwebview.this, DownloadOther.class);
                                                i2.putExtras(bundle);
                                                startActivityForResult(i2, 0);
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else if(url1.contains("mydownloads=true"))
                                        {   
                                            Log.d("its in Mydownloadssss",url1.toString());
                                            Intent i3=new Intent(Loginwebview.this,Downloadlist.class);
                                            i3.putExtras(bundle);
                                            startActivityForResult(i3, 0);
                                        }

                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {

                                    }
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }.start();  
                            return true;
                        }    
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url1) {
                            Log.i("inside onpage", "Finished loading URL: " +url1);
                            String mainurl=url1;
                        }
                        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                            Log.e("onReceivedError", "Error: " + description);

                        }
                    });
                    webview.loadUrl("http://xxx/PublicModules/UserLoginVerify.aspx?userid=809&deviceid=DA0CE50D-0EEB-5E8E-9DCA-AED00F9BDFE5");
                }
            }
```

Comment: check the following link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

Comment: I found the following quite useful: http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html A good example with plenty of guidance as to what's actually happening behind the scenes.